# Executing stored procedures under a different database context?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Due to security constraints, each customer must have its data stored in its own database. Occasionally clients require customizations that require particular stored procedures within their area to be modified, sometimes significantly. This creates a nightmare for maintaining stored procedures across all databases. It seems like this must be a frequent issue. Are there any well-accepted standards for handling situations like this?

Some approaches I have considered:

Central database containing "standard" stored procedures. Process first checks for the existence of the stored procedure within the client database, if it doesn't exist, executes from the "standard" database. Problem: I can't figure out how to execute a stored procedure from one database and have it reference tables in another database without generating dynamic SQL. This seems like the optimal solution to me as a single stored procedure needs to be maintained, customizations are easily apparent. I just can't figure out how to make it work, if one even can. It always executed under the context of the database containing the SP.

Any customizations must be made to a copy of the standard stored procedure with a _Custom suffix. All stored procedure calls first test to see if a _Custom SP exists, calling the custom one instead of the standard one when found. Customizations are more readily apparent, however every SQL call must be prefixed with another SQL call to verify SP name. Also, any changes to "standard" stored procedures still need to be replicated across hundreds of databases.

Remove stored procedures all together. Store them instead as T-SQL statements either in files or in a table somewhere. Entirely new management system would have to be created to access, test, update the T-SQL code (Management Studio is used for this currently.)

I am looking for input on how to create a simple and elegant solution to this problem, or at least improve upon the current situation, which is to manually update each stored procedure, looking for conflicting customizations as you go.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to why a stored procedure needs to be modified from the original?  Are you adding custom columns for some customers?  Is this change *for* the customer or because your business wants to collect information on your customer that is different than the rest?  I'm just trying to understand if this is potentially a database model issue or if your database structure is actually part of the product your offering.

Comment: Some examples include modified join criteria to include or exclude records, modified fields to include additional or custom fields, filters, etc.

Answer (score 6):

There is an undocumented back door way to achieve this:

- ensure the procedure name starts with `sp_`
- place the procedure in `master`
- mark the procedure as system by executing `sp_marksystemobject 'sp_...'`

This way the procedure is 'magically' available in *every* database, and it will always act on the *local* objects. Eg. if the procedure issues `select ... from dbo.Foo` and is invoked while in the context of database `bar`, the effect will be to select from `bar.dbo.Foo`, even though the procedure was declared in `master`.

Of course, by using an undocumented procedure (`sp_marksystemobject`) you expose yourself to all the problems of using undocumented features (might change w/o warning in future release or even on SP/CU update, product support may refuse to help you etc etc).

If I would be in your shoes, I would deploy the procedure(s) on *each* tenant's DB. The real problem is one of managing changes, my favorite solution is described in [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Comment: I had read about this feature, but our solution can be deployed to remote sites and we cannot expect clients to make modifications to their master DB on shared SQL Servers for our application, nor trust an undocumented feature for a product that will need to survive several future versions of SQL that may remove this feature.

Answer (score 2):

That's when you want to move away from stored procedures, that architecture seems to rely heavily on stored procedures

[When clever goes wrong](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/10/when-clever-goes-wrong-how-etsy-overcame-poor-architectural-choices.ars)

A better approach would be to move that logic into your domain layer and use composition/polymorphism to address the differences from client to client

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first approach: you can reference tables in different database from which the stored procedure is running.  You just need to fully qualify the table name [databaseName].[schema].[tableName].[columnName].  There is no need for building a string of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean that each customer has their own separate database, or separate database *server*. If the former, then the answer above would seem obvious: reference tables via the DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName syntax (or just DatabaseName..TableName if you always use the same schema.) If the latter, then you will need to Google for exotic solutions for accessing stored procedure code from a different server.

Either way, to me this cries out for a better automated deployment solution, rather than trying to execute stored procedures across database boundaries. You could setup your stored procedure deployment solution to allow you to quickly deploy new versions of a stored procedure to all databases, or just a subset. What if the customer requests a working self-contained copy of their database? This seems to me a much better solution.

Duplicating code is not always a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Super old post, but you *could* suffix your custom stored procs with a ClientIdentifier?

```
dbo.sp_getOrders  
dbo.sp_getOrders_xyz123
```

Then every standard proc has a ClientIdentifier param that would attempt to call the custom proc, if it exists.

Then all your code is in one DB, with one set of source code, any customisations are obvious (and who they belong to), deployment and source control is simple.

depending on clients access to their databases, I'd probably obfuscate the clientId...